# C++ seems to stop running at string

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and development in general. Frankly, I have no idea what is going on. I'm just trying to display a string on one line, but the program is giving me a confusing error.

I would really appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// This program calculates and displays to user
int main()
{
// Constants are state and county taxes.
const float STATE_TAX_RATE = 0.04,
            COUNTY_TAX_RATE = 0.02;

// float variables are :
float   gross_sales = 0,
        net_sales = 0,
        county_tax_payment = 0,
        state_tax_payment = 0,
        total_tax_payment = 0;

// string variable
string  month;

// integer variable
int     year;

// Get month, year, and sales information from user
cout << "For what month is this? (Please type the name of the month.)\nAnswer: ";
getline(cin, month);
cout << "For what year?\nAnswer: ";
cin >> year;
cout << "How much was total sales at the register?\nAnswer: ";
cin >> gross_sales;

// Calculate the net income
net_sales = (gross_sales)/(1 + STATE_TAX_RATE + COUNTY_TAX_RATE);

// Calculate total taxes paid.
total_tax_payment = (gross_sales - net_sales);
//    cout << total_tax_payment;    // output test

// Calculate total state taxes paid.
state_tax_payment = (total_tax_payment * (2.0/3.0));
//   cout << state_tax_payment;    //output test

// Calculate county taxes paid.
county_tax_payment = (total_tax_payment * (1.0/3.0));

//Display the information
cout << "Month: " << month << " " << year << endl;
cout << "--------------------" << endl;
cout << "Total collected:\t $" << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2) << right << gross_sales << endl;
cout << "Sales: \t\t\t\t $" << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2) << right << net_sales << endl;
cout << "County Sales Tax:\t $" << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2) << right << county_tax_payment << endl;
cout << "State Sales Tax:\t $" << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2) << right << state_tax_payment << endl;
cout << "Total Sales Tax:\t $" << fixed << setw(9) << setprecision(2)  << right << total_tax_payment << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

**For what month is this? (Please type the name of the month.)**

**Answer:** March

**For what year?**

**Answer:** 2008

**How much was total sales at the register?**

**Answer:** 26572.89

**(lldb)**

At "(lldb)" The program just stops... and Xcode indicates something I don't understand on "cout << "Month: " << month << " " << year << end;", telling where an issue is, then a lot of complex debugging info. The indicator is green colored.

Thanks again for any help!!!

Comment: Perhaps a typo:  `endl` instead of `end` (note the last letter)?

Comment: Another problem is that for `state_tax_payment = net_sales / state_tax_payment;`, you are dividing a non-initialized variable `state_tax_payment`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll correct and edit that now.

Comment: Ok, I initialized the variables at the beginning of the program, and corrected the typo... The build succeeds, but the same error persists. I'll update my code to reflect changes.

Comment: I think you may have meant to use `#include <string>` instead of strings.h

Comment: `1/3` is zero (remainder one). You don't want integer division. Perhaps you want `1.0/3.0` and `2.0/3.0`?

Comment: Can you try typing `bt` to get a backtrace.

Comment: @DavidSchwatz Thanks! That fixed the assignments so they aren't zero... BUT maddeningly, the same error persists...

Comment: You still have errors, but none that should cause it to terminate on that line.  Are you sure you didn't accidentally set a breakpoint in the debugger?  You can see the code (with more fixes) running fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b16fc0cdfcd4504d).

Comment: @Tony D... I think you're onto something there! Wow... Thanks, that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was identified by Tony D.

**The debugger in Xcode had a breakpoint set to the particular line of code. I simply had to drag it out of the gutter. For those who don't know, that the green arrow on the left in of the lines of code is a breakpoint. Drag it to the bottom, out of the code, to remove it.**

I'm sure I made a total newbie mistake, since I am one, but lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

Because `state_tax_payment` and `total_tax_payment` are not initialize `state_tax_payment = net_sales / state_tax_payment;` and  `county_tax_payment = net_sales / county_tax_payment;` lines can be result in undefined behavior

1. Initialize the all float variables
2. Assign some value to  `state_tax_payment` and `total_tax_payment`
3. Correct the type mention by ' Thomas Matthews'.

Then your program works fine . May be it exit after execution finish. so you can add something like 'getchar()' , std::cin.get() to pause the console.

Comment: Thanks you, the corrections are made, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: month std::__1::string "March" 
total_tax_payment float 13673.4287 13673.4287
state_tax_payment float 0 0
year int 2008 2008
county_tax_payment float 0 0

Comment: ^That's in the debug window

Comment: Did you assign some value to `county_tax_payment`

Comment: I'm not sure... I thought the following statement did that:
**county_tax_payment = total_tax_payment * (1/3);**

Comment: How would you assign it?